# Access Progress Bar in a separate window by code in another window

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin, gtk, gtk#

I have a GTK C# Application.During a long computation it is required to show the progress bar.I show this in a new window.But i dont know how to access the progress bar from another window ie:Main window.In winforms there was an access modifier i used to set it to public.In the properties in Xamarin studio its not there.

```
myapp.Window1 w = new myapp.Window1 ();
    w.Show ();
```

I want something like this `w.mycoolprogressbar` and update it from Main Window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using stetic to design your dialog boxes, then every container/widget will be private.

Why don't you (maybe you did, the question is quite old now) add some public method to update the progress bar?

So you'll have the following calling code:

```
var progressDialog = new ProgressDialog();

...

progressDialog.UpdateProgress(progress);
```

On the other hand:

```
public partial class ProgressDialog : Gtk.Dialog
{

   ...

    public void UpdateProgress(double progress)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah,the question is a little old.I put the progress bar in the same window now it works good.I have deleted the old code.The problem should be the one you suggested.I will create a mock project and try it out.Thanks for the answer.

Comment: thanks it worked.Im using a new window to display progress.How i can i center this window on the parent.I tried setting the parent (progress.parent=this) and using the property centeronparent.Does not work.

Comment: I know there's a method like `window.SetPosition(WindowPosition.Center);`, but I have never used it.